# resharper unit test inheritance

Tags: c#, unit-testing, resharper

Has anyone got a strategy for unit testing heiarchies in Resharper?

I typically use both TestDriven.Net and Resharper's test runner, with NUnit tests. TestDriven is awesome for everything but quickly finding a bad test out of a batch run (which could be thousands), which is where Resharper's runner comes in.

I typically use a pattern with an abstract base class (like the code below) of test cases overridden to get the right subclass, which works great in TestDriven, but Resharper just ignores them! I had thought as of v5.0 Resharper was using NUnit's code base, which means this should work but it doesn't.

Cheers,
Berryl

```
[TestFixture]
public class AdminAccountTests : AccountTests
{
    protected override Account _GetAccount() { return new AdminAccount(_idScheme, _description); }
}

[TestFixture]
public class LeaveTimeAccountTests : AccountTests
{
    protected override Account _GetAccount() { return new LeaveTimeAccount(_idScheme, _description); }
}

public abstract class AccountTests
{
    protected abstract Account _GetAccount();

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        _account = _GetAccount();
    }

    [Test]
    public void OnCreation_Blah() {
        Assert.That(_account.IdScheme, Is.EqualTo(_idScheme));
    }

}
```

Comment: This was an issue that's already been fixed for some time in the nightly builds of 5.1. Two days ago we released the latest 5.1.1. Please download that.

Comment: @Hadi. I also installed the latest NUnit (2.5.7.10213), and yes, life is good again. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your abstract class a `TestFixture`.  I do this same thing with R#.

EDIT: I just noticed that R# (I'm using 5.1 with NUnit 2.6) will mark a class as a test fixture if it has `Test`s in it, regardless of whether the subclass or the base class are attributed with `TestFixture`.  So that may not solve your problem.

Comment: I did try that, with no luck. Thanks for the reply tho

Comment: @RootBeer. See Hadi's response, sounds like he is with Jet Brains, and indicates this was a problem that has been fixed in the latest R# 5.1.1 release. I also installed the latest NUnit while I was at it (2.5.7.10213). The code I posted now executes in R#. Cheers!

Comment: Good to hear.  Thanks for the check!

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue with MbUnit and Gallio with resharper 5.1.3000.12. If i try to launch the test through visual studio plugin, the test is ignored. With external gallio test runner, it works fine.

JetBrains ReSharper 5.1 C# Edition
Build 5.1.3000.12 on 2011-01-28T05:05:56

Plugins: 
1. “Gallio Test Runner” v3.2.0.0 by Gallio
Visual Studio 9.0.30729.1.

Copyright © 2003–2011 JetBrains s.r.o.. All rights reserved.